# Chrome DevTools listen to multiple selections of the same element in the elements panel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In my Google Chrome DevTools Extension I try to listen to the selections in the DevTools panel "Elements". In particular, it should be possible to listen to the selection of the already selected element.

My current implementation method revolves around the function `chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged`. The function name already suggests that it is only possible to react to elements that are not currently selected. 
Therefore I tried to reset or remove the current selection with the help variable `$0`, to be able to listen to the same element again - unfortunately without success.

My goal is to somehow listen to every click/selection in the elements panel. In summary, I am looking for an `onSelection` listener instead of an `onSelectonChange` listener.

**EDIT #1**

Here's my code I've tried:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(
    "Selector",
    function(sidebar) {
        // It fires if I'm selecting a specific DOM element via the elements panel the first time
        // It won't fire if I'm selecting the same DOM element again
        chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(() => {
            chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(`(${getSelector})()`,
            selector => {
                console.log(selector)
                // Here I tried to reset the current selection...
                // I've already debugged it: I can assign a value to $0, 
                // but this implies that the value remains constant even 
                // after a new selection.
                chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval('$0 = undefined')
            })
        })
    }
)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to change the selector programmatically...

Comment: Got any code? What have you tried?

Comment: @shadoe2020 Please see my edit #1, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution actually.

It looks like I overlooked the function `inspect(<domElement>)` in the Chrome DevTools documentation. With this function it is possible to programmatically change the auxiliary variable `$0`. I call `inspect(document.body)` at the end of each `chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener()` function call, thus all other DOM elements become selectable again (several times).

Note: Ideally you should call `inspect(<domElement>)`  on that DOM element where you know you don't want to select it multiple times.

I hope that I could help someone with the same problem.